# Boost Karma, reordering struct elements

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

Say I have a struct like so:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int a;
    int b; 
    int c;
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT
(
    MyStruct,
    (int, a)
    (int, b)
    (int, c)
)
```

And then if I have a simple generator:

```
struct MyStructGenerator
    : boost::spirit::karma::grammar<boost::spirit::ostream_iterator, MyStruct()>
{
    MyStructGenerator() : MyStructGenerator::base_type(start_)
    {

        namespace bsk = boost::spirit::karma;

        start_ = '<' 
            << bsk::int_
            << ','
            << bsk::int_
            << ','
            << bsk::int_
            << '>';
    }

    ~MyStructGenerator() = default;
    boost::spirit::karma::rule<boost::spirit::ostream_iterator, MyStruct()> start_;
};
```

And I run the following:

```
int main()
{
    MyStruct ms = { 3, 2, 1 };
    std::cout << boost::spirit::karma::format(MyStructGenerator(), ms) << std::endl;
}
```

I, of course, expect to see `<3, 2, 1>`. What I cannot figure out is how to change the order within the rule? What if I wanted to see `<1, 2, 3>` or even if I wanted to see `<2, 1, 3>`?

Also, is there anyway I could do this without `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use phoenix and bind to access the member values.
So for your example to swap the member it would be like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/bind/bind_member_variable.hpp>
using namespace std;
struct MyStruct {
    int a;
    int b; 
    int c;
};

struct MyStructGenerator : boost::spirit::karma::grammar<boost::spirit::ostream_iterator, MyStruct()>
{
    MyStructGenerator() : MyStructGenerator::base_type(start_)
    {
        namespace bsk = boost::spirit::karma;
        start_ = '<' 
            << bsk::int_[bsk::_1 = boost::phoenix::bind(&MyStruct::c, bsk::_val)]
            << ','
            << bsk::int_[bsk::_1 = boost::phoenix::bind(&MyStruct::b, bsk::_val)]
            << ','
            << bsk::int_[bsk::_1 = boost::phoenix::bind(&MyStruct::a, bsk::_val)]
            << '>';
    }

    ~MyStructGenerator() = default;
    boost::spirit::karma::rule<boost::spirit::ostream_iterator, MyStruct()> start_;
};

int main() {
    MyStruct ms = { 3, 2, 1 };
    std::cout << boost::spirit::karma::format(MyStructGenerator(), ms) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Wow. I spent too long :) Note however this sample sorts under the one section I labeled "Don't though" in my answer. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil

Comment: @sehe: I know that you should not use `Semantic Actions` but for a quick hack I found them to be very useful. But as always when it comes to spirit/karma your answer is as complete as it only can be ;-)

Answer (score 3):

### **Q1** What if I wanted to see <1, 2, 3> or even if I wanted to see `<2, 1, 3>`

Just change the adapted order:

Simplified **<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Wc670hkuXvhnM524)</kbd>**:

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>

struct MyStruct { int a, b, c; };
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(MyStruct, a, b, c)

#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
namespace bsk = boost::spirit::karma;

template <typename It = boost::spirit::ostream_iterator>
struct MyGen : bsk::grammar<It, MyStruct()> {
    MyGen() : MyGen::base_type(start_) {
        using namespace bsk;
        start_ = '<' << int_ << ',' << int_ << ',' << int_ << '>';
    }
  private:
    bsk::rule<It, MyStruct()> start_;
};

int main() {
    MyGen<> gen;
    std::cout << format(gen, MyStruct { 3, 2, 1 }) << "\n";
}
```

Prints `<3,2,1>`, but with

```
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(MyStruct, c, b, a)
```

Prints `<1,2,3>`.

### Q2 Without Adapting?

Well. I can show you a couple of things that might interest you:

1. without Karma: **<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DxXzAH49qRbzIL1K)</kbd>**:

   ```
   #include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>

   struct MyStruct { int a, b, c; };
   BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(MyStruct, c, b, a)

   #include <iostream>
   #include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>
   #include <boost/fusion/include/as_vector.hpp>
   using boost::fusion::as_vector;

   int main() {
       MyStruct ms { 3, 2, 1 };
       std::cout << as_vector(ms) << "\n";

       std::cout 
           << boost::fusion::tuple_open("<")
           << boost::fusion::tuple_delimiter(",")
           << boost::fusion::tuple_close(">");

       std::cout << as_vector(ms) << "\n";
   }
   ```

   Prints

   ```
   (1 2 3)
   <1,2,3>
   ```
2. Named adaptations: you can adapt different orders *at the same time* by using the `*_NAMED` macros. Here's a demo that shows it both using Fusion IO and the Karma generator.

   > Note I slightly modified the struct so it's easier to track which field is `'a'`, `'b'` or `'c'`.

   See it **<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9tVr8HPXeBx8B82e)</kbd>**:

   ```
   #include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>

   struct MyStruct { char a, b, c; };
   BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT_NAMED(MyStruct, AsABC, a, b, c)
   BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT_NAMED(MyStruct, AsBCA, b, c, a)
   BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT_NAMED(MyStruct, AsCBA, c, b, a)

   #include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
   #include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
   namespace bsk = boost::spirit::karma;

   template <typename Attr, typename It = boost::spirit::ostream_iterator>
   struct MyGen : bsk::grammar<It, Attr()> {
       MyGen() : MyGen::base_type(start_) {
           using namespace bsk;
           start_ = '<' << auto_ << ',' << auto_ << ',' << auto_ << '>';
       }
     private:
       bsk::rule<It, Attr()> start_;
   };

   #include <iostream>
   #include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>
   #include <boost/fusion/include/as_vector.hpp>
   using boost::fusion::as_vector;

   template <typename Attr>
   void do_tests(Attr const& ms) {
       std::cout << as_vector(ms) << "\n";
       std::cout << format(MyGen<Attr>{}, ms) << "\n";
   }

   int main() {
       std::cout << boost::fusion::tuple_open("<") << boost::fusion::tuple_delimiter(",") << boost::fusion::tuple_close(">");

       MyStruct ms { 'a', 'b', 'c' };

       using namespace boost::fusion::adapted;
       do_tests(AsABC{ms});
       do_tests(AsCBA{ms});
       do_tests(AsBCA{ms});
   }
   ```

   Prints

   ```
   <a,b,c>
   <a,b,c>
   <c,b,a>
   <c,b,a>
   <b,c,a>
   <b,c,a>
   ```
3. Yes you can do without adapting (don't though):

   **<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hzROzXb91KEj1bRW)</kbd>** (commenting parts because of compiletime limitations)

   ```
   struct MyStruct { char a, b, c; };

   #include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
   #include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
   namespace bsk = boost::spirit::karma;
   namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

   template <typename It = boost::spirit::ostream_iterator>
   struct MyGen : bsk::grammar<It, MyStruct()> {
       MyGen() : MyGen::base_type(start_) {
           using boost::proto::deep_copy;
           using namespace bsk;
           auto A = deep_copy(char_[ _1 = phx::bind(&MyStruct::a, _val) ]);
           auto B = deep_copy(char_[ _1 = phx::bind(&MyStruct::b, _val) ]);
           auto C = deep_copy(char_[ _1 = phx::bind(&MyStruct::c, _val) ]);
           start_ =
               '<' << A << ',' << B << ',' << C << '>' << eol <<
               '<' << A << ',' << C << ',' << B << '>' << eol <<
               '<' << B << ',' << A << ',' << C << '>' << eol <<
               '<' << C << ',' << A << ',' << B << '>' << eol <<
               '<' << B << ',' << C << ',' << A << '>' << eol <<
               '<' << C << ',' << B << ',' << A << '>' << eol
               ;
       }
     private:
       bsk::rule<It, MyStruct()> start_;
   };

   int main() {
       std::cout << format(MyGen<>{}, MyStruct { 'a', 'b', 'c' });
   }
   ```

   Prints

   ```
   <a,b,c>
   <a,c,b>
   <b,a,c>
   <c,a,b>
   <b,c,a>
   <c,b,a>
   ```

Comment: Very thorough answer, as always. [This](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/example/karma/reorder_struct.cpp) is another possible approach.